# ACT! Password Decryption

Tags: password-recovery

I have a need to migrate data out of an Act! database into another system and would like to maintain the passwords from ACT! to the new system.

Is there any way to decrypt the password?  Is anyone aware of at least the algorithm used?

Answer (score 1):

Act! password recovery
http://www.act.com/support/databaseservices/password/  right side - related terms
http://www.tucows.com/preview/284171